How to handle HTTP 429 in Spring Boot AI App?
I am trying to develop a application using spring Gen AI.
Endpoint returns a Http 429 error code
Error response: I ran into this error below
retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 429 
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:57) ~[adapter-rxjava2-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:38) ~[adapter-rxjava2-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:48) ~[adapter-rxjava2-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:35) ~[adapter-rxjava2-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2517) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2001) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.theokanning.openai.service.OpenAiService.execute(OpenAiService.java:260) ~[service-0.12.0.jar:na]
    at com.theokanning.openai.service.OpenAiService.createChatCompletion(OpenAiService.java:129) ~[service-0.12.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ai.openai.client.OpenAiClient.getAiResponse(OpenAiClient.java:110) ~[spring-ai-openai-0.2.0-20230929.130618-53.jar:0.2.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.ai.openai.client.OpenAiClient.generate(OpenAiClient.java:91) ~[spring-ai-openai-0.2.0-20230929.130618-53.jar:0.2.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.spring.ai.example.com.spring.ai.example.service.SpringAIService.getJoke(SpringAIService.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.spring.ai.example.com.spring.ai.example.controller.SpringAIController.getJoke(SpringAIController.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2024-05-30T17:21:08.054+05:30 ERROR 12808 --- [com.spring.ai.example] [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: com.theokanning.openai.OpenAiHttpException: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.] with root cause

retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException: HTTP 429 
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:57) ~[adapter-rxjava2-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable$BodyObserver.onNext(BodyObservable.java:38) ~[adapter-rxjava2-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:48) ~[adapter-rxjava2-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:35) ~[adapter-rxjava2-2.9.0.jar:na]
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10151) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:2517) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2001) ~[rxjava-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at com.theokanning.openai.service.OpenAiService.execute(OpenAiService.java:260) ~[service-0.12.0.jar:na]
    at com.theokanning.openai.service.OpenAiService.createChatCompletion(OpenAiService.java:129) ~[service-0.12.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ai.openai.client.OpenAiClient.getAiResponse(OpenAiClient.java:110) ~[spring-ai-openai-0.2.0-20230929.130618-53.jar:0.2.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.ai.openai.client.OpenAiClient.generate(OpenAiClient.java:91) ~[spring-ai-openai-0.2.0-20230929.130618-53.jar:0.2.0-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.spring.ai.example.com.spring.ai.example.service.SpringAIService.getJoke(SpringAIService.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.spring.ai.example.com.spring.ai.example.controller.SpringAIController.getJoke(SpringAIController.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:389) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.24.jar:10.1.24]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

What could be the reason behind the error: HTTP 429 (too many requests)
Spring version: 3.3.0
Java :17

The error message says "You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details". You only have to pay them more :-) !

I used open AI API key first time. just went to https://platform.openai.com/api-keys and created key to authenticate test endpoints. I thought it's free may be

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It's spring boot application and trying hit the end point and got the above error.  here is sample code: @Autowired AiClient aiClient; @Value("${spring.ai.openai.apikey}") private String apiKey; @Value("${spring.ai.openai.imageUrl}") private String openAIImageUrl; public String getJoke(String topic){ PromptTemplate promptTemplate = new PromptTemplate(""" Crafting a compilation of programming jokes for my website. Would you like me to create a joke about {topic}? """); promptTemplate.add("topic", topic); return this.aiClient.generate(promptTemplate.create()).getGeneration().getText(); }
